# In kql, how can I convert `make-series` in to table?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

The following query returns the data that I need:

```
let timeSpn = bin(ago(60m),1m);
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == "myApp"
| where success == "False"
| where timestamp > timeSpn
| make-series count() on timestamp from timeSpn to now() step 1m by application_Version
```

The problem is that the result consist of 2 lines (one for each `application_Version` and not 120 lines (one for each minute and for each version).

I have to use `make-series` and not the simple `summarize` because I need the "zero" values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the [**`mv-expand` operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)

Here's an example from [Back-fill Missing Dates With Zeros in a Time Chart](https://4pp1n51ght5.com/2018/12/19/back-fill-missing-dates-with-zeros-in-a-time-chart/):

> ```js
> let start=floor(ago(3d), 1d);
> let end=floor(now(), 1d);
> let interval=5m;
> requests
> | where timestamp > start
> | make-series counter=count() default=0 
>               on timestamp in range(start, end, interval)
> | mvexpand timestamp, counter
> | project todatetime(timestamp), toint(counter)
> | render timechart
> ```

Comment: `mvexpand` is deprecated and will only expand 128 rows. Use `mv-expand` instead.

Comment: It seems you can even render a timeschart without the `mvexpand` or `project` lines in the query. Don't know if that's new functionality which KQL/AI only didn't have before.

Comment: @comecme yes, you can use the `bin` operator on the summary clause, the problem is that missing data are "blanks regions", so when you look at the image, you will see a very weird line connecting 2 widely separeted dots